# Instantly deleting a reply on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I replied to a comment by mistake and instantly deleted it.  Is the reply off instantly? I don't see the reply anymore but someone commented on how rude my reply was. So it must have been seen.

Answer (score 1):

When a comment is deleted, all the associated replies also get deleted.

In your case, if you have deleted your comment and you are still seeing someone commented which relates your comment, that means the person didn't use the *reply* button to reply to your comment. The comment was made by using the original comment's *reply* or a fresh comment on the post.

And if someone has replied targeting your comment that means it must have been seen before you deleted it.